# Simple thing: How to connect new .h and .m to storyboard Xcode

Tags: xcode, linker, storyboard

Ive written the code in a new .m file, but I don't know how to link it to the storyboard as to make it run the code. any help please? a new .m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag a new ViewController into the storyboard. Now select the File's Owner for this new ViewController. Go to custom class and set the class to MyViewController which you have created as MyViewController.m       Now you can use this new ViewController for  MyViewController. Also, [see this](http://kurrytran.blogspot.in/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html)

Comment: yes set the class there to the one you created, keep in mind if you are dragging a view controller in storyboard then the class you created should also be a derived class of UIViewController

Comment: Worked thanks, just had to figure out where the custom class thing was